# Can not download my own artifact from maven central using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, maven-publish, maven-repository

I published successfully a simple project to maven central using maven-publish plugin in gradle.

You can see package [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.github.0123456hahaha0123456/example/1.0.2/jar).

You can found my code of published project on [github](https://github.com/0123456hahaha0123456/example).

But when I tried to implement it from new gradle project, always fail.

```
Could not resolve io.github.0123456hahaha0123456:example:1.0.2.
```

I don't know where I was wrong. Please help to check it.
Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Download using maven

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.github.0123456hahaha0123456</groupId>
 <artifactId>example</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Download use gradle groovy

```
apply plugin 'groovy'

dependencies {
    implementation "io.github.0123456hahaha0123456:example:1.0.2"
}
```

Comment: How did you publish? There are strict rules in place.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I followed the rules. Btw, I published via Sonatype OSSRH. You can check my [build.gradle](https://github.com/0123456hahaha0123456/example/blob/main/build.gradle)

Comment: Maven resolves your artefact without problems, it looks as if you have published correctly. Have you retried resolving it? Or maybe clearing come gradle caches? I use maven so that's just a shot in the dark really.

Comment: @Chaosfire I retried clean caches and refresh dependencies but It did not work.

Comment: I am out of ideas then, here is a [similar problem](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cannot-resolve-dependencies-that-are-resolved-by-maven/18894) i found on the gradle forums, might be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I updated my question.
My problem is on [my artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.github.0123456hahaha0123456/example/1.0.2/jar) page, Maven shows `Gradle Groovy DSL` command to download it.
But I forgot add plugin `groovy` in my build.gradle file.

**Solution:**

Add line below in gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).